# Name of philosopher who wrote about language mutations

Tags: german-philosophy

Could you please tell me the name of a philosopher who wrote text about language mutations?
As far as I remember he has 'Max' in the name.
More then, one day he said something like: "Commune kills individualism"

I'm so bad in psychology, but he is something near Jaspers, Wittgenstein or such, in school knowledge lectures story line.

Comment: "Language *mutations*" ?

Comment: [Ludwig Wittgenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Wittgenstein) ?

Comment: "Commune kills individualism" ? Maybe *communism* ...

Comment: There is no logic in assumption like : "communism kills individualism". Those are completely different dimensions of abstraction.

Comment: What are language mutations?

Comment: I am almost sure this is Max Horkheimer arguing against Stalinism (not Socialism). He wrote about how language is used against rationality and utilised. But have not yet been successful in finding a good quote on that.

Comment: Btw Horkheimer speaks of *language distortions*, not *mutations*.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Max Stirner?

> On the Contrary, Communism, by the abolition of all personal property, only presses me back still more into dependence on another, viz., on the generality or collectivity; and, loudly as it always attacks the "State," what it intends is itself again a State, a status, a condition hindering my free movement, a sovereign power over me. Communism rightly revolts against the pressure I experience from individual proprietors; but still more horrible is the might that it puts in the hands of the collectivity.

Max Stirner, *The Ego and Its Own*, ed. David Leopold (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 1995)